# How do I to get the Intent from Activity B which started the Activiy A, when Activity A was started before

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have two Activities: Activity A and Activity B:

'A' is my Main Activity, and it has a Button to Activity B. And 'B' has a Button to 'A'. And now is my Question how I can find out that the User is coming from Activity B.

When I use "getIntent()" it is the Intent from the Main Activity, but I need the 
Intent from the Activity B.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are passing the intent from Activity B you have to create a new itent and  just add some extra data with it to to identify it. Like 
I n t e n t i n t e n t = n ew I n t e n t ( t h i s ,  A c t i v i t yA . c l a s s ) ; i n t e n t . p u t E x t r a ( " c a l l e r " , " A c t i v i t yB " ) ;
 s t a r t A c t i v i t y ( i n t e n t ) ;

And in Activity A fetch the extra data using getIntent().getExtras()  methods.

like 
S t r i n g c a l l e r = g e t I n t e n t ( ) . g e t S t r i n g E x t r a ( " c a l l e r " ) ;

Comment: That does cause a NullPointerException because the getIntent() Method returns the Intent, which started the Activity A and thats not Activity B.

Comment: Yes definitely. So you have to create in instance of intent for Activity B

Comment: this new intent object for B holds the data for B. You were using something else. This was the issue . Mark it as answer so it help people furthur.

Answer (score 2):

try this

In **Activity A**(Main Activity ):-

```
 @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(getIntent().getStringExtra("fromActivtyB") !=null)
        {
            String str=getIntent().getStringExtra("fromActivtyB");
            Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and in **Activity B**:

```
            Intent inten=new Intent(this,ActivitttestappActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Activty b", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            inten.putExtra("fromActivtyB", "Actiity B");
            this.startActivity(inten);
```